# Do I need use Gzip in a Rails 4 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, gzip

I'm running some audits in my open-source project, [BTC-Stores](http://www.btc-stores.com), and some times Chrome shows me that I need "Enable Gzip compression".

Sometime ago I read "High Performance Websites", from Steve Souders, and I already know the basic concepts about how make your page load faster. My project is using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.

**I want know, Rails 4 already have a "gzip like compression" or I need to activate it by some gem or config?** If you can, please link some good articles about Rails 4 performance and how to optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some more about using gzip with Rails!

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html:

> 4.1.2 GZip Compression
>
> When files are precompiled, Sprockets also creates a gzipped (.gz)
>   version of your assets. Web servers are typically configured to use a
>   moderate compression ratio as a compromise, but since precompilation
>   happens once, Sprockets uses the maximum compression ratio, thus
>   reducing the size of the data transfer to the minimum. On the other
>   hand, web servers can be configured to serve compressed content
>   directly from disk, rather than deflating non-compressed files
>   themselves.
>
> Nginx is able to do this automatically enabling gzip_static:
>
> location ~ ^/(assets)/  {   root /path/to/public;   gzip_static on; #
>   to serve pre-gzipped version   expires max;   add_header Cache-Control
>   public; } This directive is available if the core module that provides
>   this feature was compiled with the web server. Ubuntu packages, even
>   nginx-light have the module compiled. Otherwise, you may need to
>   perform a manual compilation:
>
> ./configure --with-http_gzip_static_module If you're compiling nginx
>   with Phusion Passenger you'll need to pass that option when prompted.
>
> A robust configuration for Apache is possible but tricky; please
>   Google around. (Or help update this Guide if you have a good example
>   configuration for Apache.)

Also, the following may be of interest!

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Gzip.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will give you the best answer because your post have a link that I can follow and read about Gzip in Rails. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to use Gzip in a Rails 4 or any other project. You do that in the production server and not on your local.

Duplicated question: [Compressing rails assets and nginx gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734608/compressing-rails-assets-and-nginx-gzip) (with nginx server)

Comment: Thanks for little explanation! :)